# Doing two counts on a single table in a single query

Tags: postgresql

There are some similar questions/answers on the forums but I think my problem is simpler.

I have two quesries, eg

```
SELECT count(*) FROM agent;
SELECT count(*) FROM agent WHERE active = 't';
```

I would like the output to be on a single row.  For bonus points it would be nice to scan through the table only once and update both counters, to get a result like this

```
active_agents | total_agents
--------------+--------------
    10        |     20
```

So I guess I have two questions:
What is the Neatest/clearest way to do this, and
What is the fastest way to do it for very large tables.

Comment: If active is a bool (and I hope it is), you don't actually need `= 't';` The bool itself works, and that may be more *neat*, because that's the goal here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html) statement for this scenario:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_agents, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN active = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active_agents
FROM Agent;
```

Sample execution with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Agent (Id INT, Active CHAR(10));

INSERT INTO Agent (Active)
VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('t'), ('c'), ('t'), ('d');

SELECT count(*) AS total_agents, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN active = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active_agents
FROM Agent;
```

Comment: Your field names are backwards - count(*) should be for total agents, conditional sum for active agents.

Comment: @mbeckish Thanks for pointing out. Alias name updated.

Comment: And there are several shortenings: `count(nullif(active,false))` or `sum(active::int)`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this a couple of others ways. [In addition to Arulkumar's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177117/2639)

## Sample data

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo(x) AS
  VALUES (true),(false),(false),(true),(false);
```

## Using `FILTER`

I prefer this method because it's syntactically simpler to the `SUM()` method, but both work the same way.

```
SELECT
  count(*)                  AS count_total,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE x) AS count_where_x
FROM foo;
 count_total | count_where_x 
-------------+---------------
           5 |             2
(1 row)
```

## With `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`

If you want the results pivoted,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT x, count(*)
FROM foo
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((x),())
HAVING x IS TRUE
  OR x IS NULL;
 x | count 
---+-------
 t |     2   -- this is where x = true
   |     5   -- this is the total
(2 rows)
```

Or, if you really want to have fun..

```
HAVING x IS NOT false;
```

Because that just sounds cool.

Comment: `falase`? Is that intentional?